# How to trim the output of the UNIX who Command?

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I am working with an idea using the unix `who` command.  As we all know, there does not seem to be a direct switch that gives just the username and line (terminal) info without the date and screen info... eg:  the output is `mneedham tty7...2012-02-19 11:26 (:0)`

What I am trying to get is just the `mneedham tty7` part.  The solution needs to work no matter how long the username and terminal information.

I tried using `tr -s ' '` (one space) like `who | tr -s ' '` and that gave me one space between everything.  Not quite what I was seeking.  Tried `cut -d" " -f1` gets the username only.  So I am hopeful someone can help me find the right command to get both bits of information.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `-f 1-2` with `cut`? That is, `who | cut -d' ' -f 1-2` "works here", ymmv. (`-f 1` selects only one field.)

Answer (score 13):

Using cut:

```
who | cut -d " " -f1,2
```

Using awk:

```
who | awk '{ print $1, $2 }'
```